How do I get rid of the gap between divs caused by display flex?
Here's what it looks like in visual code

I keep getting a gap between my container and pages divs, I can get rid of it by removing display:flex from the css, but that misaligns the video, overlay and content. How can I get rid of the gap without throwing everything off?


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #292626;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.container .content{
    opacity: 0.75;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

body{
    font-family: 'MontFont', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0rem;
}

.Holmes1{
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 950;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    mix-blend-mode:
    difference;
}
.Park1{
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 950;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    mix-blend-mode:
    difference;
}
.ContactME1{
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 950;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    mix-blend-mode:
    difference;
}
.Pages{
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
section{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
.Holmespage{
    background-color: #373333;
}
.Parkpage{
    background-color: #292626;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Pages">
    <section class="Holmespage">
        <div class="Holmes1">HOLMES</div>
    </section>
    <section class="Parkpage">
        <div class="Park1">PARK</div>
    </section>
    <section class="Contactpage">
        <div class="ContactME1">CONTACT</div>
    </section>
  </div>



I've tried to change the margin to 0, negative and positive amounts, including trying on the top and bottom margin separately, not sure if it's cause I'm not applying it to the right place. Also tried to use Display: flex box but that didn't work, and using flex: 1

It's not clear to me what "gap" you're referring to.  The result of the code snippet isn't obvious.  Can you update the example to demonstrate the problem?

It looks like the gaps are caused by the scrollbars, could you try removing the width: 100vw; from the container class? Block elements take up the full width by default, so it's not really needed.

@David I've updated the code, it's not fully appearing like it does in visual code when I run it

Try to add display: flex; and gap: 0; to your class .Pages.

whenever there is need to reduce the gap in between flex box you can simply achieve it by adding
gap:0;

however if the div inside flex is relatively positioned you can achieve it by adding width equals to calc(100% / n) where n is number of divs inside the flex.
